# Number of multiples of a polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials

Given a positive integer $n$, give an asymptotic estimate of the number of polynomials with integer coefficients $p(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_0$ such that $|a_i|\le \binom{n}{i}$ for each $i=0,1,\ldots,n$ and $p(2/5)=0$.

---

The choice of the root $2/5$ could be replaced by any algebraic number: I don't know if it is a known problem or no.. in case, does someone have a reference?

Comment: I think my first answer was not quite correct. It really depends on what the root $r$ is. In a lot of situations $r$ just won't even have a solution for your choices of $a_i$.

Comment: For $n$ enough large, it should not have a solution if and only if $r$ is not algebraic :)

Comment: The issue is the growth rate of the polynomial. For example if you pick $a_0,...a_{n-1}$ the mean is zero, but it looks like the variance will be quite large. This means that for a lot of choices of the first $n-1$ coefficients, there won't be an $a_n$ if $r$ is too big.

Comment: In truth, it would be enough to consider the case $r \in (0,1)$; nevertheless it should not make difference, at least for the existence of such a polynomial..